# Python, Pandas to combine Excel files into 1, with files names as Column A

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am combining Excel spreadsheets into 1 spreadsheet, and want to insert the filenames of the spreadsheets as first column when they are combined.

The Excel files to be combined are: 20170801.xlsx, 20170901.xlsx, 20171001.xlsx

This is the code I have:

```
working_folder = 'c:\\abc\\'
files = os.listdir(working_folder)

files_xls = [];
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".xlsx"):
        fff = working_folder + f
        files_xls.append(fff)

df = pd.DataFrame();

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, skip_footer=0)
    file_date = basename(f).replace(".xlsx", "")
    #data.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("", file_date)] * len(data))
    data.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(file_date)] * len(data))
    df = df.append(data)

df.to_excel(working_folder + 'final.xls', merge_cells = False)
```

The problem lies in the *line data.index = pd.MultiIndex*….

When I use:

```
data.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(file_date)] * len(data))
```

it produce a spreadhsheet like this:

[image]

When I use:

data.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("", file_date)] * len(data))

It produce a better looking spreadsheet but an empty column A like this:
[image]

Not to use MultiIndex, how can I have a final spreadsheet looked like this?

[image: enter the image description here]

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you needed a multi index?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thank you for the comment. I know it's not needed. But i don't know what to use...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you dont need `MultiIndex`, only change:

```
data.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(file_date)] * len(data))
```

to:

```
data.index = [file_date] * len(data)
```